# Additional object wrappers in JSON generated by Rails

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Rails 3 controller:

```
class EmployeeController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def index
    employees = Employee.all
    respond_with employees
  end
end
```

If I put in a pry breakpoint and call `to_json` on `employees`, I get what I expect - the serialization of an array of JSON objects, whose properties are the attributes on my `Employee` ActiveRecord model:

```
[1] pry(#<EmployeeController>)> employees.to_json
=> "[{\"created_at\":\"2013-06-21T19:22:14Z\",\"email\":\"ian@ ...
```

However, by the time the JSON result is returned from the controller, it has acquired *two* additional layers of object wrappers: one around the list itself, and one around each object:

```
{"employee":[{"employee":{"created_at":"2013-06-21T19:22:14Z","email":"ian@ ...
```

The library I'm working with isn't expecting these additional wrapper layers. Which part of Rails is responsible for adding them, and is this a behaviour I can control?

Version:

```
$ rails -v
Rails 3.2.13
```

**Update**

JSON gem versions:

```
$ grep -i json Gemfile.lock 
    multi_json (~> 1.0)
    multi_json (~> 1.0)
  json (1.8.0)
  multi_json (1.7.7)
    json (~> 1.4)
    multi_json (~> 1.0)
    multi_json (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Call

```
ActiveRecord::Base.include_root_in_json = false
```

before rendering and see what you get.

If it works, put

```
# Disable root element in JSON by default.
ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do
  self.include_root_in_json = false
end
```

in your config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb.

Comment: That sounds like it's the behaviour that I'm experiencing, but `include_root_in_json` is already false, and the default is already set that way in `wrap_parameters.rb`. It makes me wonder if my JSON libs are appropriate - I'll update the question with my JSON gems.

Comment: Interesting.. Can you try an older version of json gem?